# Matlab - How can I find the lowest common directory of an arbitrary group of files?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of full file names and I want to find the lowest common directory where it makes sense to store accumulated data and what not.

Here is an example hierarchy of test data:

```
    C:\Test\Run1\data1
    C:\Test\Run1\data2
    C:\Test\Run1\data3
    C:\Test\Run2\data1
    C:\Test\Run2\data2
      .
      .
      .
```

In Matlab, the paths are stored in a cell array as follows (each run shares a row):

```
    filePaths = {...
        'C:\Test\Run1\data1','C:\Test\Run1\data2','C:\Test\Run1\data3'; ...
        'C:\Test\Run2\data1','C:\Test\Run2\data2','C:\Test\Run2\data3'};
```

I want to write a routine that outputs the common path `C:\Test\Run1` so that I can store relevant plots in a new directory there.

```
    C:\Test\Run1\Accumulation_Plots
    C:\Test\Run2\Accumulation_Plots
      .
      .
      .
```

Previously, I was only concerned with two files in an x-by-2 cell, so the regiment below worked; however, `strcmp` lost it's appeal since I can't (AFAIK) index the whole cell at once.

```
    d = 1;
    while strcmp(filePaths{1}(1:d),filePaths{2}(1:d))
        d = d + 1;
    end
    common_directory = filePaths{1}(1:d-1);
    mkdir(common_directory,'Accumulation_Plots');
```

Comment: is there something else at the end of the array or just those names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @nekomatic, I'm posting my comment as an answer.

```
filePaths = {...
    'C:\Test\Run1\data1','C:\Test\Run1\data2','C:\Test\Run1\data3'; ...
    'C:\Test\Run2\data1','C:\Test\Run2\data2','C:\Test\Run2\data3'};

% Sort the file paths
temp = sort(filePaths(:));

% Take the first and the last one, and split by '\'
first = strsplit(temp{1}, '\');
last = strsplit(temp{end}, '\');

% Compare them up to the depth of the smallest. Find the 'first N matching values'
sizeMin = min(numel(first), numel(last));
N = find(~[cellfun(@strcmp, first(1:sizeMin), last(1:sizeMin)) 0], 1, 'first') - 1;

% Get the smallest common path
commonPath = strjoin(first(1:N), '\');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up going with this option, but opted to use

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up going with this option with the following changes:

`% Find the 'first N+1 matching values`
[~,N] = intersect(~cellfun(@strcmp, first(1:sizeMin), last(1:sizeMin)), 1);

% Get the smallest common path
commonPath = fullfile(first{1:N-1});`

Any reason to use `find(,,'first')` and `strjoin()` over `intersect` and `fullfile`?

Comment: Sure `fullfile` would be better, I just forgot it. As for `intersect`, try with this counterexample `filePaths = {'C:\Test\Run1' 'C:\Test'}`. Didn' work here.

Comment: I found that if the paths only have the drive letter in common, this solution returns `C:` while mine returns `C:\\` (with a backslash - excuse my Markdown). I don't think either is right or wrong but it might be worth checking if that makes a difference to the rest of your code.

Comment: @nekomatic, thanks for pointing that out.  I generally use `fullfile` anytime I'm creating a directory string, so I think that discrepancy can be negated - `fullfile` ignores any _single_ file seperator.  I also wrote in a special condition (with a warning message) for when no common directory exists.  In my case I made it default to `C:\`.

Comment: If you want to have your code work on unix platforms as well, replace '\' by <code>filesep</code>.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to compare the first `d` characters of any path in the array - e.g. path 1 - with the first `d` characters of the other paths. The longest common base path can't be longer than path 1 and it can't be shorter than the shortest common base path between path 1 and any other path.

There must be several ways you could do that, but a concise one is using `strfind` to match the strings and `cellfun` with `isempty` to check which ones didn't match:

```
% filePaths should contain at least two paths
filePaths = {...
    'C:\Test\Run1\data1','C:\Test\Run1\data2','C:\Test\Run1\data3'; ...
    'C:\Test\Run2\data1','C:\Test\Run2\data2','C:\Test\Run2\data3'};

path1 = filePaths{1};
filePaths = filePaths(2:end);

% find longest common left-anchored substring
d = 1;
while ~any(cellfun(@isempty, strfind(filePaths, path1(1:d))))
    d = d + 1;
end

% find common base path from substring
[common_directory, ~, ~] = fileparts(path1(1:d));
```

Your code leaves `d` containing the length of the longest common left-anchored substring between the paths, but that might be longer than the common base path; `fileparts` extracts the actual base path from that substring.

Comment: You could sort the paths and compare the first with the last one.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro good call, you could. You should post that as an answer.